# How to prevent default behavior when middle click on a link (browsers' extensions)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

In my Firefox's & Google Chrome's extensions I can prevent default behavior when middle click on a link like this:

```
function onClick(e) {
    var url = getLink(e);
    if (e.button == 1) { // Middle Click
        // prevent opening a link
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        // do something with a link
        // url ...
    }
}
if (browser == "chrome")
    document.addEventListener("auxclick", onClick); // for Google Chrome (old "click" event doesn't prevent opening link with middle click but they added "auxclick" for this)
else if (browser == "firefox") 
    document.addEventListener("click", onClick); // for Firefox (still works)
```

also https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/auxclick, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/auxclick

I'm also trying to do this for my Microsoft Edge's extension, but seems middle click event for this browser doesn't work at all:

```
function onClick(e) {
    var url = getLink(e);
    if (e.button == 1) { // Middle Click
        alert("hello"); // isn't working for Microsoft Edge
    }
}
document.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

So instead of this for Microsoft Edge I use:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    while (target) {
        if (target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement)
            break;
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (e.button == 1 && target.href != null) {
        alert("hello"); // works when middle click on a link
        // but these preventing doesn't works here:
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        // link will still be opened in a new tab
    }
});
```

But this method doesn't prevent link from opening in a new tab when middle click

How can I make Microsoft Edge behave like Google Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: try using onmouseup instead of onmousedown.

Comment: @RobParsons there would be no difference

Comment: created this issue on Microsoft site: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18351424/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the latest version of Edge has event listener `auxclick` now, the same as Chrome, because Edge is based on Chromium engine now, not EdgeHTML